# Does spell check in HTML5 support all languages?

Tags: html, spell-checking

I would like to know whether spell check in HTML5 support all languages. Is there any reference available for the same anywhere in the internet ?

Thanks,
Aromal

Comment: That will greatly depend on the implementing browser.

Comment: I don't think HTML5 has spell check at all.

Comment: Hi torazaburo, HTML5 does support spell check. I have used it in many of my projects.Please see the below link. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.spellcheck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `spellcheck` attribute is used to inform the browser whether or not it should apply spell-checking to an `input` element (*this defaults to false*).

```
<textarea spellcheck="true"></textarea>
```

You can identify a language which the browser should use to spell-check an element:

```
<textarea lang="en"></textarea>
```

If the user does not have a dictionary installed for that language then the spell check is disabled for that element.

So to answer your question - `spellcheck` itself does not support any languages, it is a flag to identify whether a browser should spell check an `input` element.

#### References

- [Spellcheck](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/spellcheck)
- [Controlling spell checking in HTML forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_formsControlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms)

Comment: Thanks. When you say "if the user doesn't have a dictionary installed for that language", does that mean the user should install dictionary for that language as a browser plugin ?

Comment: Yes, users can install the dictionary required using their browser. The following browsers have examples how to do this: [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-firefox-spell-checker#w_adding-dictionaries), [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95604?hl=en), [Opera](http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.10/en/spellchecker.html)